# java.exe not found when running ireport 5.1

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

Whenever i run the ireport 5.1 i always get the error: `java.exe not found`

already tried changing the `ireport.conf` directory of jdk to
`jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"`

also tried creating a new system variable. `JAVA_HOME` with the same filepath

but none of it is working

seriously need some help here

Comment: .config file wants jdk Home Directory. not the jre I think. Your are providing `jre` directory in `ireport.conf`. This might be a Problem.

Comment: also tried that.used this directory `jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin"`
 still with the same result

Comment: try this `jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`. No bin directory

Comment: still the same. i have no idea what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Open the `ireport.conf` file in `iReport/etc` directory

After the comment

```
# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
```

Insert

```
jdkhome="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_79"
```

where `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_79` is an installed jdk

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. Download the iReport 5.1 .zip from jaspersoft
2. Unzip the folder, now the folder is iReport-5.1.0
3. Download the jre-7u79-windows-i586.tar file from oracle site
4. Untar this file and copy the folder jre1.7.0_79 from it.
5. Place this jre1.7.0_79 folder (same location where the bin, etc exists)
   into the iReport-5.1.0
6. Go to etc/iReport.conf, open this file.
7. Edit the file with this, remove the existing jdkhome path :
   jdkhome=".\jre1.7.0_79"
8. Launch the iReport.

I was able to fix with these steps. Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Install JRE version 7. In `ireport.conf` use:

```
jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```

and not

```
jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\\".
```

Comment: Looks to me like you wrote the same value (for `jdkhome`) twice. Or am I mistaken? By the way, you can use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your posts.